# Best way to go about handling client/server swing gui using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple client and server gui, there are 2 client guis/frames (a user can switch to a different gui and go back for an unknown amount of times), I wanted to know what would be the best approach for a use-case like this.

I've tried using SwingWorker, but then my server would stop handling requests after about 10 times of going back and fourth between the 2 client guis, I'm aware I could set a number of threads to use but since I won't know how many times a user will switch guis, I couldn't get it to work using that.

I'm currently using a FixedThreadPool, the number of threads in the pool is also what I'm not sure about (currently I'm using this to set it to the # of cores the computer has -> Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

The problem now is that, I can move back and forth between guis, but sometimes the program would hang after about 20 times, although it is rare, it does seem to happen, and when I try to print out the current thread, I always get something like this, the thread # doesn't seem to change, only the pool # does.

**pool-27-thread-1**

Here is my code

**Server**

```
public class Testserver {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket client;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
     private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public Testserver() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void listenForClients() {
        try {

            while (true) {
                client = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("client connected");
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                processClient();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Testserver().listenForClients();
        });
    }
    

    private void processClient() {
        System.out.println("CORES: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        
        executor.execute(() -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        do {
            try {
                String messageFromClient = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                System.out.println("[CLIENT] " + messageFromClient);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            }
        } while (true);
        });
        
        executor.shutdown();
        
    }

}
```

---

**CustomerGUI**

```
public class CustomerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private Socket server;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private JButton btnAdminGUI;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    
    public CustomerGUI()  {
        
        btnAdminGUI = new JButton("Go to Admin GUI");
               
        try {
            server = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        btnAdminGUI.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new CustomerGUI().setGUI();
        });
    }
    
    public void setGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(btnAdminGUI);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource() == btnAdminGUI) {
           new AdminGUI().setGUI();  
           dispose();
       }
    }
}
```

The other GUI, AdminGUI is pretty much the same, just goes to the CustomerGUI after clicking a button.

[image: Output when printing current thread in the server]

Comment: The `CustomerGUI` doesn't seem to interact with `objectOutputStream` or `objectInputStream` at all. It creates a new `AdminGUI` instance each time the button is clicked. If `AdminGUI` is the same, then each button click will establish a new connection to the server, without closing any existing ones.

Comment: Also, each client connection creates a new thread _pool_ on the server. You probably want to share a single thread pool, created when the server starts.

Comment: Also, does the server need to support more than one connected client? Right now, there is only one field for the client `socket`, `objectInputStream`, and `objectOutputStream`. Each new connection will replace those without closing the existing connection.